# CSS float and responsive behaviour

Tags: css, responsive-design, css-float

Here is my template:

```
<div id="block1">text</div>
<div id="block2">
   <span>content of variable size</span>   
</div>
```

and some basic CSS

```
#block1 {
    float:left;
}

#block2 {
    float:right;
}

#block2 span {     
}
```

When reducing the `width`, how could I make it behave so that, once the two `div`s cannot fit the page inline, the second `div` will go below the first (rather than be right floated anymore)?

**NOTE:** I would like to avoid using media queries.

This responsive theme CSS would be used for multiple sites with content of different sizes.

**[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/bkp3tvhb/)**

In this current JSFiddle, The second div is on the right hand-side. It is fine to me.

If possible without media queries, i would like to design css so that once the second div goes below , the span content is not at the right-hand side

Comment: It's not clear what you are asking for and there isn't enough CSS to provide any meaningful answers. - https://jsfiddle.net/bkp3tvhb/1/

Comment: Also, any responsive these **should** be using media queries...that's what they are for.

Comment: @Paulie_D your quick reply suggest it might not be the most thoughtful answer

Comment: You vague question is too broad. There is no magic bullet to responsiveness, You have to use multiple techniques including media queries. You won't be able to cram a desktop page into a mobile screen without extra work.

Comment: @Paulie_D i am hoping constructive replies. I know i can use media queries. To me, its usage comes when you have found no better options for adaptative css

Answer (score 2):

If you mean "I want div2 to go below, but aligned left this time", it's not possible as this behaviour is not predictable using CSS only.

There's no CSS-way to know when it goes below, so impossible to change the floating attribute at this moment.

You could achieve this using Javascript or jQuery. Logic would be:

```
on ( window resize ) {
    if ( div1_width + div2_width > container_width ) {
        Change div2 CSS.
    }
}
```

Of course I would suggest to use media queries too.

Answer (score 1):

You can set min-width on the divs. Then, when the line is too small, the one on the right will drop down. However, it will still be floated which may cause issues. That's where media queries come into play to fix such things.

Answer (score 1):

Too many media queries would not make for a pretty responsive design, not to mention they would be a headache.

Anyway, you would have to use at least one media query to achieve a truly responsive design, the simplest example is below:

```
<div id="block1">text</div>
<div id="block2"> <span>content of variable size</span> 
</div>  


* {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
#block1 {
    float:left;
    height: 200px;
    background: yellow;
    width: 49.5%;
    margin-right: .5%;
}
#block2 {
    float:right;
    height: 200px;
    background: tomato;
    width: 49.5%;
    margin-left: .5%;
}
#block2 span {
}
@media only screen and (max-width : 768px) {
    #block1 {
        float:none;
        width: 100%;
    }
    #block2 {
        float:none;
        width: 100%;
    }
}
```

Fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/0bgsnhau/).

If you want to have a look at something more practical, a good starting point is [here](http://tympanus.net/codrops/2014/03/21/responsive-full-width-tabs/)(its an example of an accordion changing layouts depending on screen size, using media queries).